# Identifying independent & dependent clauses in a religious text

Tags: clauses, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

> Ephesians 6:14-17
>
> 14 Stand firm therefore, having belted your waist with truth, and having put on the breastplate of righteousness, 15 and having strapped on your feet the preparation of the gospel of peace; 16 [a]in addition to all, taking up the shield of faith with which you will be able to extinguish all the flaming arrows of the evil one. 17 And take the helmet of salvation and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is my attempted answer:

[image: Text of Ephesians 6:14-17]

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @JohnLawler i have attached my answers can u help me check?

Comment: The second red one is dependent, not independent. A clause whose main verb is a participle (_taking up_ in this case) can't be independent. Otherwise fine. Why does it matter? Undoubtedly it was different in the original Greek.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you!